# Should I use 'which' on filters?

Tags: r

When filtering a dataset you can use:

```
df[df$column==value,]
```

or

```
df[which(df$column==value),]
```

The first filter returns a logical vector. The second one returns a list of indexes (the ones which value is 'True' in that logical vector). Should I use one better than the other? I see that sometimes the first one returns a row with all values as NA...

Which of both expression is more correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should (almost) always prefer the first version.

Why? **Because it’s simpler.** Don’t add unnecessary complexity to your code — programming is hard enough as it is, we do not want to make it even harder; and small complexities add to each other supra-linearly.

One case where you might want to use `which` is when your input contains NAs that you want to ignore:

```
df = data.frame(column = c(1, NA, 2, 3))

df[df$column == 1, ]
# 1 NA

df[which(df$column == 1), ]
# 1
```

However, *even in this case* I would not use `which`; instead, I would handle the presence of NAs *explicitly* to document that the code expects NAs and *wants* to handle them. The idea is, once again, to make the code as simple and self-explanatory as possibly. This implies being explicit about your intent, instead of hiding it behind non-obvious functions.

That is, in the presence of NAs I would use the following instead of `which`:

```
df[! is.na(df$column) & df$column == 1, ]
```